# How to consume BlockingCollection<'a>.TryTake in F#

Tags: f#, tuples, task-parallel-library

How do I go about using the TryTake method on a BlockingCollection<'a> passing in a timeout period in milliseconds?

Heres the signature:

***BlockingCollection.TryTake(item: byref, millisecondsTimeout: int) : bool***

is it possible to use the Tuple method of avoiding passing a ref type like on the Dictionary.TryGet methods?

i.e.
***let success, item = myDictionary.TryGetValue(client)***

Im struggling with this particular signature, any suggestions would be great.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you can only use that technique for `byref` parameters which occur at the *end* of the parameter list (this is similar to the rule for optional parameters).  So if `BlockingCollection.TryTake` were defined with signature `int * 'T byref -> bool` it would work, but since it's defined as `'T byref * int -> bool` it won't.

For example:

```
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

type T =
  static member Meth1(a:int, [<Out>]b:string byref, [<Out>]c:bool byref) : char = 
    b <- sprintf "%i" a
    c <- a % 2 = 0
    char a
  static member Meth2([<Out>]b:string byref, [<Out>]c:bool byref, a:int) : char = 
    b <- sprintf "%i" a
    c <- a % 2 = 0
    char a

//  ok
let (r,b,c) = T.Meth1(5)
//  ok
let (r,c) = T.Meth1(5,ref "test")
// ok
let r = T.Meth1(5, ref "test", ref true)
// doesn't compile
let (r,b,c) = T.Meth2(5)
// doesn't compile
let (r,c) = T.Meth2(ref "test", 5)
// ok
let r = T.Meth2(ref "test", ref true, 5)
```

Comment: Given that, if I had to do a lot of work with BlockingCollection from F#, I'd probably make an extension method overload of TryTake that accepts an integer and returns a tuple.

Comment: Ill have to look into that as I will be using it quite a bit, managed to get myself confused creating the **ref T** thats passed in