# Using BlockingCollection<'a>.TryTake in F#

Tags: f#

This is related to an old question:

[How to consume BlockingCollection<'a>.TryTake in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927649/how-to-consume-blockingcollectiona-trytake-in-f?rq=1)

where the answer is more or less that we can't use it because the byref part should be at the end of the parameter list to make it possible.

8 years have passed since this question: are there any similar blocking queues with a timeout that I can use in F#?

Comment: Note: You can use that method from BlockingCollection in F# just fine - it just won't do the "translation to tuple return" automatically because of the order of arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TryTake` from F# without issues, but you can't use it as tuple returns. For exmaple, in FSI, this code:

```
open System.Collections.Concurrent

let bc = new BlockingCollection<int>()
let mutable item = 0

bc.Add 42
let success = bc.TryTake(&item, 100)
```

Will work fine, and result in the following output:

```
val bc : BlockingCollection<int>
val mutable item : int = 42
val success : bool = true
```